# Pulling a Maybe out of a Tuple in Purescript

Tags: purescript

I have a function that looks like this:

```hs
import Data.Bifunctor (lmap)
import Data.Int (fromString)

keyToInt :: forall a. Tuple String a -> Tuple (Maybe Int) a
keyToInt = lmap fromString
```

What I'd like is this type signature:

```hs
keyToInt :: forall a. Tuple String a -> Maybe (Tuple Int a)
```

This seems to work:

```hs
keyToInt :: forall a. Tuple String a -> Maybe (Tuple Int a)
keyToInt tuple = extractFstMaybe $ lmap fromString tuple
  where
    extractFstMaybe :: forall a. Tuple (Maybe Int) a -> Maybe (Tuple Int a)
    extractFstMaybe (Tuple (Just a) b) = Just $ Tuple a b
    extractFstMaybe (Tuple Nothing _) = Nothing
```

But it feels like there should be a more abstract/cleaner way to express this. If I were to take `extractMaybe` to it's natural conclusion, I might create something like

```hs
-- The typing doesn't really work for this
extractMaybe :: forall a b c d. (Tuple a b) -> Maybe (Tuple c d)
extractMaybe (Tuple (Just a) (Just b)) = Just $ Tuple a b
extractMaybe (Tuple (Just a) b) = Just $ Tuple a b
extractMaybe (Tuple a (Just b)) = Just $ Tuple a b
extractMaybe (Tuple Nothing _) = Nothing
extractMaybe (Tuple _ Nothing) = Nothing
extractMaybe (Tuple a b) = Just $ Tuple a b
```

While reading about applicatives and bind, this is the sort of refactoring I would see a lot. I don't really have the experience yet to apply those lessons for myself.

If I have a structure that may contain an ADT (An Array of `Either`s, or `Maybe`s, or `Array`s) and I want to define a way pulling those "out," is there a generalized way to define that?

---

[Purescript by Example](https://book.purescript.org/chapter7.html) has an example with this type signature for a function:

```hs
combineList :: forall f a. Applicative f => List (f a) -> f (List a)
```

which is doing the same thing, only for a List. N-Tuples complicate this because every element can have a different type. If I call `extractMaybe` on a Tuple, I now a have a Tuple with any types **except** for `Maybe` (or I have `Nothing`).

I could write the same thing for `Either` and if I use both, I could know I have a Tuple with any types **except** for `Maybe` and `Either` (or I have `Nothing`).

I'm not even entirely sure this is the most helpful direction to go in. It seems helpful in situations like `mapMaybe` where you want to filter out all `Nothing`s and `Left`s while unwrapping those types as well.

Comment: It's not really clear what your overall question is, so it's hard to answer! But you're right that your `extractFstMaybe` can be written more abstractly/cleanly. The section of Purescript by Example that you link to is about `Traversable`, and since `Maybe` is `Applicative` and `Tuple a` is `Traversable`, `sequence` can be specialised to the type `forall a b. Tuple a (Maybe b) -> Maybe (Tuple a b)`. That's not quite what you want, because it "extracts" the wrong element of the tuple - but (TBC)...

Comment: (continued from above): [swap](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-tuples/6.0.0/docs/Data.Tuple#v:swap) comes to your rescue - so you can write `extractFstMaybe = map swap . sequence . swap`

Comment: Thanks. Took me a bit, but this does make sense. I wound up re-writing it as `swap >>> sequence >>> map swap` and that somehow clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might program this as:

```
keyToInt (Tuple a b) = ado
  a' <- fromString a
  in Tuple a' b
```

because it is close to many similar needs. You can easily apply something to `b`, or pattern match on something other than Tuple, or combine the result with something other than Tuple.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly [`ltraverse`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foldable-traversable/3.1.0/docs/Data.Bitraversable#v:ltraverse):

```
module Main where

import Data.Bitraversable (ltraverse)
import Data.Int (fromString)
import Data.Tuple (Tuple)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe)

keyToInt :: forall a. Tuple String a -> Maybe (Tuple Int a)
keyToInt = ltraverse fromString
```

Whenever you're destructuring a type and constructing it back within another type (e.g. `Maybe`) that's when you want to `traverse`. In this case, `Tuple` has two things you can traverse over, making it `Bitraversable`. For this function, you want to traverse over the left hand side of the `Tuple` - i.e. `ltraverse`.